# assign smarty variable in php / mysql query

Tags: php, smarty, phpfox

I am working in phpfox.I want to use smarty variable in mysql query.
I have searched a lot and apply all methods / solutions available in stackoverflow but its not working.

Comment: what did you try, pls show your code

Comment: My smarty vaiable value = $aPin.ITEMID
Now I want to use this value in below query:

$q= "SELECT Count( DISTINCT `user_id` ) AS totalMembers FROM phpfox_event_invite
WHERE event_id =$aPin.ITEMID"

Answer (score 0):

Use [get_template_vars](http://www.smarty.net/docsv2/en/api.get.template.vars.tpl) to get template variable in php code

```
$myVar = $smarty->get_template_vars('aPin');
echo $myVar.ITEMID;
```

Also try get_template_vars() to get the list of all assigned variables

```
$myvar = $smarty->get_template_vars();
print_r($myvar);
```

Comment: Appreciated for your quick response,
I have used this solution but this is not working in my case.

Comment: Please post your code in your question, otherwise it is really hard for us to help you.

Comment: I have given code in comment also like my value in smarty variable like {$aPin.ITEMID} now I want to use this in mysql query like for an exa.  select from Tablename where is = {$aPin.ITEMID} but not working.

Comment: @yogeshK what output are you getting from  $smarty->get_template_vars() ??